# Upload image and video on Firebase Storage and save URL in Firestore using Java

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have checked the docs provided by Google, but it doesn't metioned how to upload image and video.

```
Map<String, Object> city = new HashMap<>();
city.put("name", "Los Angeles");
city.put("state", "CA");
city.put("country", "USA");

db.collection("cities").document("LA")
        .set(city)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
            }
        });
```

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, then this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will definitely help. Here is also the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).

Answer (score 1):

**To upload images/videos on Firebase, you need to use Firebase Storage -**

1. Check the below document link for upload file on Firebase storage

   https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files
2. Once you upload the file on Firebase storage you will get a download URL save that URL in Firestore for future reference
3. You can access your image/video using that download URL

Hope you understood, let me know if more information is required.

Comment: In this case, the downloading URL rather than media files themselves are stored in Firestore? Is it possible to upload images/videos to Firestore? Thank you!

Comment: actually, i don't know that `firestore` has stored your image or videos or not. but `upload image or videos in storage` and then you will find 'download URL', you can use that `URL` to access that image or videos. thats work for me.